# is the faces API no longer available on bluemix?

Tags: ibm-cloud

The faces API on public bluemix appeared to stop working.

We call it and we get a timeout on the URL now.

Is this expected?

Comment: can you please add a sample of the API your getting timeout?

Comment: http://faces.w3ibm.bluemix.net/api/find/ ...